# Safari flexbox & margin-top: auto with dynamic content

Tags: css, safari, sass, flexbox

Using a flexbox layout, I have a left column navigation where the menu is at the top and a little copyright footer that sticks to the bottom using the `margin-top: auto;` method. The page is in a React App where the component is calling out to an API to get data after initial paint. Once loaded the content area then expands beyond the viewport. I'm not using 100vh so I'd expect it would expand to the rest of the document like Chrome & Firefox does. Instead the copyright and navigation stays the height of the viewport upon scrolling down to view the rest of the page.

Currently it works in Firefox & Chrome but not Safari. Probably a little extra css doing nothing on the parents since I was troubleshooting.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.app {
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-content: stretch;

  .AppContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    align-content: stretch;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100vw;

    .navigation-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      height: 100%;

      .navigation {
        width: 220px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
      }

      .footer {
        margin-top: auto;
        color: #CCC;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        line-height: 1.6rem;
        padding: 0 20px 20px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried align-self: „flex-end“ on footer

Comment: I had not but just did. Had zero effect good or bad.

Comment: In further research `.navigation-container` is not getting the height of 100%;

Comment: Try to remove `align-items: flex-start; height: 100%;` from `.AppContainer` and remove `height: 100%;` from `.navigation-container` ... if this doesn't help, you need to provide a working code snippet reproducing the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `position: relative` to `.navigation-container` and `position: absolute` to `.footer`. Seemingly only affects Safari. The other browsers could care less without additional properties for positioning in this case.